# Cannot connect 2 data on Neo4j using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to connect ”The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring” with "Percy Jackson" finding from the database with following code

```
MATCH (n:Movie {title: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring'})<-[:DIRECTED]-(Person)
CREATE p = (Person) - [r:`DIRECTED`] ->(title)
RETURN p
```

When I execute it, I am having the following graph.

[Result from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXAxi.png)

My question is that why movie's name is not shown and how I can solve it?

I tried to search on the web but i guess the version is not same with mine.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you assume that the relationship 'Directed' exists between the movie with title 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring' and an unnamed person (Person)

Then you try and create a relationship based on that match, this causes confusing behavior.

You can match the movie using

```
MATCH (m:Movie {title:<title>})
```

and match a person

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: <name>})
```

then you can create a relationship DIRECTED between those two with a CREATE

```
CREATE (p) - [:Directed] -> (m)
```

NOTE: CREATE always creates, MERGE matches and creates if not exists (VERY basic explanation. for more see: [CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/create/) and [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/))

There are free courses available on [NEO4J](https://neo4j.com/developer/developer_courses/)